# Remove attachments from BIM 360 issue

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I following this link to [Adds a BIM 360 Document Management file to a BIM 360 issue.](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/field-issues-attachments-POST/). Is there any API to remove these attachments after attached to issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at it if issues attachment is using [relationships API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/relationship-service-v2-add-relationships-PUT/). If so, I thought we may be able to use [POST relationships:delete](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/relationship-service-v2-delete-relationships-POST/). Unfortunately, it does not look like Issues uses relationships API.

As a side note, moving forward, references are defined by relationships API, which is a common components in BIM 360 and ACC now. For example, Assets uses relationships extensively. Issues in ACC will be using relationships API to define references.